# Is list(set) operation O(1) in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, set

if we want to construct a list from a set, we can do

```
[k for k in set]
```

This is O(n) operation, meanwhile:

```
dict.keys()
```

is O(1) 
according to https://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/ICS-33/lectures/complexitypython.txt

Thus, as far as I know, dict is using set as its keys underlying data structure, is `list(set)` O(1)? And how is this implemented?

```
a = set(range(n))
s = list(a) # is this operation O(1)?
```

Comment: What do you mean by `list(set)`? Note that `dict.keys()` returns a view, which is neither a list nor a set.

Comment: @Ry︁ that's in python3, python2 still returns a list.

Comment: Your document is about Python 3. The complexity of `dict.keys()` is O(n) in Python 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Thus, as far as I know, dict is using set as its keys underlying data structure.

Hmm, no not really.  The opposite way around is a closer analogy: in the implementation, `set` is like a `dict` with all null values.  The `dict` came first in Python, and `set` did not appear until Python 2.2 (July 2000) - see [PEP 218](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0218/).

Also worth mentioning that `dict.keys()` is O(1) since Python 3.  In Python 2 it's O(n) and you should use `dict.viewkeys()` for the keys "view" (set-like interface).

> is `list(set)` O(1)?

No, it's O(n) - just the same as the list comprehension.

> And how is this implemented?

Sets support [the iterator protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/iter.html).